# The git (or python) command requires the command line developer tools

Tags: python, xcode, macos, oh-my-zsh, xcode-command-line-tools

*This knowledge post isn't a duplication of other similar ones, since it's related to 12/September/2022 Xcode update, which demands a different kind of solution*

I have come to my computer today and discovered that nothing runs on my terminal Every time I have opened my IDE (VS Code or PyCharm), it has given me this message in the start of the terminal.

I saw so many solutions, which have said to uninstall `pyenv` and install python via brew, which was a terrible idea, because I need different python versions for different projects.

Also, people spoke a lot about symlinks, which as well did not make any sense, because everything was working until yesterday.

Furthermore, overwriting `.oh-my-zsh` with a new built one did not make any difference.

Comment: Stop rolling back; meta text pointing out where to find the answers when it's highlighted by the site itself isn't appropriate or necessary to include.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I was prompted to reinstall commandLine tools over and over when trying to accept the terms

I FIXED this by opening xcode and confirming the new update information

Comment: I did NOT need to completely uninstall xcode. I did try to reinstall commandline tools before opening xcode

Comment: I have not received any alert on Xcode update (If I had seen this post, maybe I would open Xcode and also see it ;) ). I have reinstalled command line tools so many times, that killing everything once and for all, was the easiest solution :) lol

Comment: The macOS update to 12.6 triggered this as well for me. Just start Xcode and select the development environments and everything works again afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

in my case I had to open Xcode after installing the update to "fix" git

Answer (score 5):

Also solved by by running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` after installing the command line tools

Answer (score 3):

Didn't need to delete/reinstall Xcode, just installing the new Xcode update fixed this for me

Answer (score 1):

Apple have released an update for their Xcode today. This update has broken the command line tools.

Deleting completely Xcode and command line tool and reinstalling them have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different Xcode versions like me
(one living on documents and the other as an application on Launchpad)
you need to open the one which is on the Launchpad and accept the terms, otherwise is going to keep asking for the command line tools to download every time.
That fixed my issue.